# terraform s3 inventory on an existing bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to make the [example](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_inventory) from terraform registry to work, but with an existing bucket (s3XXXprod0). I have applied this days ago but still no paquet file was seen on the inventory bucket. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, or what to do in order to debug it. The inventory bucket gets created and no error message appears while applying the config:

```
provider "aws" {
  profile = "default"
  region  = "us-east-2"
}


data "aws_s3_bucket" "s3XXXprod0" {
  bucket = "mybucketXXX-prod0"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "inventory" {
  bucket = "mybucketXXX-prod0-inventory"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_inventory" "s3inventory" {
  bucket = data.aws_s3_bucket.s3XXXprod0.id
  name   = "EntireBucketDaily"

  included_object_versions = "All"

  schedule {
    frequency = "Daily"
  }

  destination {
    bucket {
      format     = "Parquet"
      bucket_arn = aws_s3_bucket.inventory.arn
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT:
after several days, no parquet file seen, the message on 
Amazon S3 > Buckets > mybucketXXX-prod0 > Management > Inventory Configuration > Last export was:

*Inventory export for 2022-07-19 failed because S3 doesn’t have     access to the destination bucket or KMS key. Ask the owner of the     destination bucket or KMS key to grant the necessary access and     then try again*

the original bucket was created on Serverless Framework and that's the beauty of multi-vendor. So, if there's a was to do this in Terraform, it's preferred although I'm not sure of the best practices here. I just need to know where to create this policy - is it a bucket policy or ACL? (or both?). thanks, M.

Comment: Are the buckets in the same account?

Comment: yes, same accnt

Comment: Are there ACLs/bucket policies on the existing bucket?

Comment: @MarkoE I don't think so, the original bucket was created with sls framework.

Comment: I don't know what that framework is, but are you able to check the bucket for policies or ACLs? Using the AWS web console.

Comment: @MarkoE get-bucket-policy on "mybucketXXX-prod0" gives me (NoSuchBucketPolicy) "The bucket policy does not exist" and ACL gives full control to my user. Thanks for helping on this btw.

Comment: No worries. I know I'm stating the obvious, but were there any objects added to the bucket after this configuration was applied?

Comment: I think we need to grant perm to s3XXXprod0 for writing on inventory, no?

Comment: This seems to be related to the KMS key used for encryption in the prod bucket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, I found this post on [github](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/5137). And thanks to Bryant Biggs I know now the policy is missing in the Terraform documentation. So here's my take:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "allow_access_policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.inventory.id
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.allow_access_policy.json
}


data "aws_iam_policy_document" "allow_access_policy" {
  statement {
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["s3.amazonaws.com"]
    }

    actions = [
      "s3:PutObject",
    ]

    resources = [
      aws_s3_bucket.inventory.arn,
      "${aws_s3_bucket.inventory.arn}/*",
    ]

    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "s3:x-amz-acl"
      values   = ["bucket-owner-full-control"]
    }
    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "aws:SourceAccount"
      values   = ["XXXXXXXX"]
    }
    condition {
      test     = "ArnLike"
      variable = "aws:SourceArn"
      values   = ["${data.aws_s3_bucket.s3XXXprod0.arn}"]
    }
  }
}
```

applied today, will see tomorrow.

EDIT:
it works! the inventory bucket has parquet files now.